# Unwanted lines showing up on rendered cube

Tags: rendering

So I have a "twisted" cube that I rendered an image from, as shown below:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to smooth out the diagonal lines on the cubes faces.

Comment: Set the smoothing to *smooth* and in the mesh properties check the autosmooth option and set the angle for cca. 60°. You should also densify the geometry

Comment: What he said ^^ A face is treated as two triangle internally in Blender for rendering and such otherwise

Comment: or you can simplesubsurf it.

Comment: Just because I want to learn, and understand... This is because the middle edge is marked as sharp?

Comment: Yes, setting it to smooth should fix that issue.

Comment: @Jerryno you may want to write your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Every quad is treated as 2 triangles, this is what is causing the problem. You need smooth shading for the edges inside the quads and sharp for the corners of the cube.

To do this set the smoothing to smooth and in the mesh properties check the auto-smooth option and set the angle for cca. 70° (depends on the twisting).

[image]

[image]

This way faces with angle with more than 70° will keep sharp shading between them.

You should also densify the geometry so it follows the ideal curved/bended surface closer.